# Need jQuery auto function

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have created simple slider for my site , It is working fine demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/Kxnh3/1/

Now i want to work this slider auto ? 
any idea ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(0) a').click(function()
     {
     jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(0)').addClass('activeSlide');
     jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(1)').removeClass('activeSlide');
     jQuery('#homeSliderSlideshow').animate({'left':'0'},'slow');
     });

     jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(1) a').click(function()
     {
     jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(0)').removeClass('activeSlide');
     jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(1)').addClass('activeSlide');
     jQuery('#homeSliderSlideshow').animate({'left':'-100px'},'slow');
     });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wraper">
    <ul id="homeSliderSlideshow">
        <li>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sliderBtn">
    <ul>
        <li class="activeSlide">
            <a href="#">1</a>
         </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">2</a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "auto"?

Comment: There are two slides 'left' and 'right'. Which needs to be done auto ?

Comment: i mean need to work without click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/irowab/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
(function($){  // remap '$' to jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    
    var c = 0;
    var t;
    var n = $('#homeSliderSlideshow li div').length/2;
    
    function actives(){
      $('.sliderBtn li:eq('+c+')').addClass('activeSlide');
      $('.sliderBtn li:eq('+c+')').siblings('li').removeClass('activeSlide');
    } 
  
    function anim(){
        $('#homeSliderSlideshow').animate({left : -(c*104)},800);        
    }
                 
    function autoAnim(){
            t = setTimeout(function(){
                c=++c%n;
                actives();
                anim();
                autoAnim();
            },2000);
    }
    autoAnim();
               
    $('.sliderBtn li').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        clearTimeout(t);
        c = $(this).index();
        actives();
        anim();
        return false;
    });
  
});

 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Great job , but you changed all my jquery script(Its not a problem) Im not a jQuery expert so i dont know how it working with your code , so im asking can you do with my own code ?

Comment: @ShibinRagh Thanks for your prompt comment. You code does not suit your needs. This code is actually really simple after I explain it to you. If you want I can walk you through it.

Comment: @ShibinRagh I'll create a demo with the comments. Just a sec.

Comment: @ Roko C. Buljan-  can you give me your skype id?  I dont know can i ask here !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11359/discussion-between-shibin-ragh-and-roko-c-buljan)

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    var value=0;
    setInterval(function(){
        value=value==0?-100:0;


        if(value==0)
        {
           jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(0)').addClass('activeSlide');
           jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(1)').removeClass('activeSlide');
        }else if(value==-100){
           jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(1)').removeClass('activeSlide');
           jQuery('.sliderBtn li:eq(0)').addClass('activeSlide');
        }


        jQuery('#homeSliderSlideshow').animate({'left': value + 'px'},'slow');
    },2000);

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/P8ex3/2/)

Comment: Make it slide 104px instead of 100 for proper alignment (you forgot to consider the borders) - http://jsfiddle.net/P8ex3/1/

Comment: @bfavaretto proper alignment is not important here this is just demo

Comment: @ankur20us , actually i like your code , but still missing active class

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) function, you can use this to cycle through the slides every few seconds.